# JQ datatables Server-side processing make 2 line of Search box and just one working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just 2 line search in top of table and i cannot find why. just 1 is working.
I have tried different changes and it is there.

Used libraries:

- https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js
- https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
- https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

```js
function createTable(columns_titel) {

  $('#deliveris').DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "ajax": {
        "url": window.location.href + '.json',
        "type": "POST",
        "dataType": "json",
        "dataSrc": function(data) {

          return data.data;
        },
      },
      "columns": [{
          "data": "delivery.LogisticsCompany"
        },
        {
          "data": "delivery.created"
        },
        {
          "data": "delivery.driver_name"
        },
        {
          "data": "delivery.car_plate_number"
        },
        {
          "data": "number"
        },
        {
          "data": "order_id"
        },
      ],
      "responsive": true,
      "autoWidth": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
      ],
      "pageLength": 20,
      "language": {
        "sEmptyTable": "Keine Daten in der Tabelle vorhanden",
        "sInfo": "_START_ bis _END_ von _TOTAL_ Einträgen",
        "sInfoEmpty": "Keine Daten vorhanden",
        "sInfoFiltered": "(gefiltert von _MAX_ Einträgen)",
        "sInfoPostFix": "",
        "sInfoThousands": ".",
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ Einträge anzeigen",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Wird geladen ..",
        "sProcessing": "Bitte warten ..",
        "sSearch": "Suchen",
        "sZeroRecords": "Keine Einträge vorhanden",
        "oPaginate": {
          "sFirst": "Erste",
          "sPrevious": "Zurück",
          "sNext": "Nächste",
          "sLast": "Letzte"
        },
        "oAria": {
          "sSortAscending": ": aktivieren, um Spalte aufsteigend zu sortieren",
          "sSortDescending": ": aktivieren, um Spalte absteigend zu sortieren"
        },
        "select": {
          "rows": {
            "_": "%d Zeilen ausgewählt",
            "0": "",
            "1": "1 Zeile ausgewählt"
          }
        },
        "buttons": {
          "print": "Drucken",
          "colvis": "Spalten",
          "copy": "Kopieren",
          "copyTitle": "In Zwischenablage kopieren",
          "copyKeys": "Taste <i>ctrl</i> oder <i>\u2318</i> + <i>C</i> um Tabelle<br>in Zwischenspeicher zu kopieren.<br><br>Um abzubrechen die Nachricht anklicken oder Escape drücken.",
          "copySuccess": {
            "_": "%d Spalten kopiert",
            "1": "1 Spalte kopiert"
          }
        }
      }
    }

  );
};

createTable("foo");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="deliveris" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <th>Spedition Name</th>
    <th>Datum</th>
    <th>Fahrer Name</th>
    <th>Autokennzeichen</th>
    <th>sendungsnummer</th>
    <th>Auftrag Nr.</th>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <th>Spedition Name</th>
    <th>Datum</th>
    <th>Fahrer Name</th>
    <th>Autokennzeichen</th>
    <th>sendungsnummer</th>
    <th>Auftrag Nr.</th>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add HTML codes to your question.

Comment: HTML code as follow
<table id="deliveris" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
 <thead>
  <th>Spedition Name</th>
  <th>Datum</th>
  <th>Fahrer Name</th>
  <th>Autokennzeichen</th>
  <th>sendungsnummer</th>
  <th>Auftrag Nr.</th>
 </thead>
 <tfoot>
  <th>Spedition Name</th>
  <th>Datum</th>
  <th>Fahrer Name</th>
  <th>Autokennzeichen</th>
  <th>sendungsnummer</th>
  <th>Auftrag Nr.</th>

 </tfoot>
</table>

Comment: Hey friend, not here. Please edit your question and add your HTML codes to question